# Minifying Javascript On Website Stops Images Loading

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am desperately trying to minify + combine all my javascript files using a wordpress plugin. I have tried a few and the same problem happens on all of them when activated my front page slider (http://www.joellepoulos.com) and none of my portfolio images show up. I have tried deactivating every javascript that is being minified and the problem remains. It seems to happen when the plugins are activated even if the plugin isn't minifying any files. I cannot figure this out - my site is so slow right now due to loads of javascript files running and minifying them helps so much but this problem is killing me!

Comment: If you want to minify your Javascript you shouldn't rely on a plugin. Most likely when the plugin is consolidating the JS it is not taking into account which code needs to be loaded first and a function is being called before it's defined.

Comment: but I'm not good enough at this kind of thing to minify it myself, even if I do combine all the files, then how and where do I upload it, etc. I have absolutely no idea...

Answer (score 0):

The code actually throws an Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: twttr is not defined
```

It's probably looking for a variable declared in another script but the minifier has changed the name. Naive minifiers don't account for outside dependencies.

I can vouch for YUI Compressor or Google Closure Compiler. Here is an online version: http://refresh-sf.com/yui/

---

I also highly recommend you use [YSlow](http://yslow.org/). It gives great tips on how to optimize your website. Minifying is good but it's effect is greatly reduced if you need to load many small Javascript files. Work towards consolidating them into as few (large) files as possible.

Comment: Thats part of the twitter eventing engine https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events